# Is there any other way to convert row fields into column other than pivot

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table in a database which I will be accessing through a viewmodel instead of directly accessing a domain model. My table looks like this:

```
placename       cafeName
  x               cafe red
  x               cafe blue
  y               cafe red
  y               cafe blue
  z               cafe red
  z               cafe blue
```

I want something like this:

```
placename         cafename   cafe name
  x               cafe red   cafe blue
  y               cafe red   cafe blue
  z               cafe red   cafe blue
```

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this? I have already tried using pivot but I ended up with a error casting a generic list to a string. I want to return that into a list to my view page.

My code looks like this :

```
 var query = from ast in db.mytable                                            
        select new ActViewModel
        {
            ScreenSetupID = ast.SetupID,
            Acame = ast.Acame             
        };
        var result = query.ToList();
        return result;
```

Comment: Maybe a bad example. but you seem to be grouping by place name--which wouldn't give you the columns the way you drew them but could easily be flattened that way.

Comment: If you want a list of cafe names for each place, a group by might be enough. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ylGJma)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. looked your Fiddle i tried group by but there is a error in casting,and i also don't want it to joined and separated by commas,may be i should detail my need little more clear,i have a    separate table of cafe names and place names both where place table have a foreign key to cafe names tables,would be happy if some one could help me out ,thanks in advance

Comment: @Bassam, can you please tell what happens if a place has 3 cafe names associated to it? How should your view model look in a generic situation?

Comment: @Bassam, if you look at the fiddle, you will see that I am getting a list of places where each has a list of cafe names. Joining as a comma separated list was just for displaying the result in the console.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. **thanks** in advance ,while grouping i am able to return only two objs in list but what if i also wanna return id along with it ,real case is  i wanna return a list to my view which should contains ID of each field,the exact thing i am trying to do is assigning roles (Concept) for each user in a forum,the first column is screen pages(from a table) and next column is permissions(from another table).while posting i want ids of each field which ever is checked [link](http://i58.tinypic.com/bi8a3a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with a simple pivot? This solution isn't generic in any way, but should give you a good start:

```
/*Thank you Daniel. J.G for the fiddle. I took it as the basis*/
public class Foo
{
    public String Place {get; set;}
    public String CafeName {get; set;}
}

List<Foo> RawFoos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo{Place = "x", CafeName = "cafe red"},
    new Foo{Place = "x", CafeName = "cafe blue"},
    new Foo{Place = "y", CafeName = "cafe red"},
    new Foo{Place = "y", CafeName = "cafe blue"},
    new Foo{Place = "z", CafeName = "cafe red"},
};

var pivot = from f in RawFoos
            group f.CafeName by f.Place into g
            //Anonymous object because I'm lazy      
            select new 
            { 
              Place = g.Key,
              CafeRed = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "cafe red"),
              CafeBlue = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "cafe blue")
            };

pivot.Dump(); // only in Linqpad
```

[image]